# Media.release() in cordova's Media plugin

Tags: android, cordova, media

How does Media.release() work. Looking at the docs it feels that you have to use it like this:

```
MediaService.loadMedia('sounds/connection-error.wav').then(function(media){
    media.play();
    media.release();
});
```

But I googled enough to know that is wrong. We have to explicitly release the core instances  on Android.

But how to do that? If I have 8 views in my app and if I play a sound file on each of those views does that count as 8 core instances being used? And can I go back to say view number 1 and again play the sound associated with that view? If so, would that count as a 9th instances ?

Straight away calling `media.release()` just like above does not play any sound at all.

Answer (score 1):

Most common way to play sounds using Cordova Media plugin is following:

```
function playAudio(src) {
    // HTML5 Audio
    if (typeof Audio != "undefined") { 
        new Audio(src).play() ;

    // Phonegap media
    } else if (typeof device != "undefined") {

        // Android needs the search path explicitly specified
        if (device.platform == 'Android') {
            src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
        }

        var mediaRes = new Media(src,
            function onSuccess() {
               // release the media resource once finished playing
               mediaRes.release();
            },
            function onError(e){
                console.log("error playing sound: " + JSON.stringify(e));
            });
         mediaRes.play();
   } else {
       console.log("no sound API to play: " + src);
   }
}
```

Comment: So` onSuccess` fires when media is finished playing? Is that correct?

Comment: Technically releasing resources inside onSuccess handler is not necessary, and you could cache resources and release them only when application pauses or exits.

Comment: (typeof Audio != "undefined") returns true for me in phonegap, causing no sound to come out. Probably needs a different way to see if you're in phonegap or not.