# Cordova media plugin - when to call release()?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I just realised there is a `release()` function in cordova media plugin. I am wondering whether you should release in the success callback after every `play()` call or some other time?

Is it more efficient to cache sounds? I have about half a dozen sound effects I am using so I could cache the media objects in an array instead of creating a new media object each time - should I do this?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590304/media-release-in-cordovas-media-plugin) on how to release, with some comments that you could cache instead of releasing every play.

Here is my code (without using any caching):

```
function playMP3(fileName, callback) {
    if (window.Media) {
        var mp3URL = getMediaURL(fileName);
        var media = new Media(mp3URL, function() {
            // success
            // release the media resource once finished playing here?
            media.release();
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }
        }, function (err) {
            // error
            jlog("failed to play mp3 file: [" + fileName + "]");
            try {
                // release the media resource once finished playing here too?
                media.release();
            } catch (e) {
                // ignore error on release
            }
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }
        });
        if (media) media.play();
    }
}

function getMediaURL(s) {
    if (window.device && window.device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android") {
        return "/android_asset/www/sounds/" + s; 
    } else {
        s = "sounds/" + s; //put everything in sounds directory
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for cordova sound effect caching I will give an update. I added some caching for good measure and it seems to work, but I don't know whether it improves memory usage or anything.

My problem was the callbacks would make it too complicated (since the callbacks end up getting cached), so I decided to simplify and just use a timer since that is all I need for most of the sounds in Speaking Email. When I need proper finish callbacks then I skip the cache.

```
function playMP3(fileName, callback) {
    if (window.Media) {
        if (!window.soundEffectCache) {
            window.soundEffectCache = {};
        }
        var sfx = window.soundEffectCache[fileName];
        if (!sfx) {
            var mp3URL = getMediaURL(fileName);
            sfx = new Media(mp3URL);
            window.soundEffectCache[fileName] = sfx;
        }
        sfx.play();
    }

    // callback is not really after finishing, just a sec after starting
    if (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 500);
    }
}
```